# Thermodynamics vs Kinetics

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, probability

As a chemical reaction approaches equilibrium, one of forward or backward reactions dominate the other. According to thermodynamics, this is because the gibbs free energy change for one is negative. In other words, it gives energetic reasons why one reaction is favoured at constant temperature. According to kinetics, however, for a system at constant temperature, equilibrium is approached when backward and forward rates match ie there seems to be no energetic reason to favour one reaction, just a probabilistic reason. What insight am I missing here? What is the relationship between probabilistic and energetic reasons?

Comment: Maybe this question would be better on Chemistry.SE http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

> As a chemical reaction approaches equilibrium, one of forward or backward reactions dominate the other.

Yes. But note the domination of one reaction (amount of its products increasing) is already implied by the assumption that system approaches chemical equilibrium. If none reaction dominated, there would already be chemical equilibrium.

> According to thermodynamics, this is because the Gibbs free energy change for one is negative.

Negative contribution of a reaction to Gibbs energy is compatible with approach to equilibrium, but it not sufficient condition for it.
In thermodynamic equilibrium that reaction will still have negative effect on $G$, only its effect will be cancelled by the opposite reaction. So the approach to equilibrium cannot be due to character of one reaction only; the other reaction is important as well and the concentrations of reactants and products are important as well.

Perhaps you think that (false). This is a variant of the idea (false) and (false).

These are common ideas but they *are not* what thermodynamics says.

The idea of thermodynamic equilibrium state and universal direction of physical processess to attain it is an inductive *assumption* about behaviour of real bodies, based on *experience* with many of them. It is made in science to justify the use of thermodynamic theory to them, since thermodynamics needs equilibrium states to express its statements in the first place.

That includes 1st and 2nd law. That's right: already the statement of 2nd law needs to use the preconceived concept of
equilibrium state and the possibility of systems to reach it. So it is a misconception in thermodynamics to think 2nd law implies physical systems change their state towards universal thermodynamic equilibrium; it is the other way around.

Remarks:

- (one form of) 2nd law states: increase of entropy of a system when its state has changed from initial eq. state $i$ to final eq. state $f$ is not lower than $\int_i^f dQ/T$.
- Note 2nd law *is not* saying entropy of an isolated system is increasing in
  time.
- In thermodynamics, if entropy of an isolated system is said to have increased, this is not meant as "increased in time", but as a comparison of two equilibrium states. Equilibrium thermodynamics does not deal with temporary states; these states and their hypothetical entropy are well outside the descriptive powers of equilibrium thermodynamics.

In statistical physics, there are also entropies (information entropy, coarse-grained entropy) some of which are functions of time, but these are generally entirely different concepts of entropy from thermodynamic entropy. If the system is in thermodynamic equilibrium, some of the many statistical concepts of entropy have the same value/dependence on constraints as thermodynamic entropy. But then they do not change in time either.

> In other words, it[Gibbs energy non-increasing] gives energetic reasons why one reaction is favoured at constant temperature.

Just to emphasize my point: one reaction is not favoured over the other one because $G$ follows some law (2nd law). Approach to equilibrium and domination of certain reactions are very common expectable processes in any non-equilibrium situation including those artificially setup by humans in a lab.

As a side note, Gibbs energy is not really an energy in the sense of (relativistic)mechanics and conservation of energy. It is a special quantity

$$
G = U - TS + PV
$$

which depends on $T,S,P,V$ besides internal energy $U$. True, $G$ has units of energy, but it is just that in chemistry, it is often preferable to express 2nd law in terms of $G$ than in terms of entropy $S$, because changes in $G$ can be easily measured as heat transferred (which is already measured in units of energy), while changes in $S$ need to be calculated from such measurements and have awkward units.

> According to kinetics, however, for a system at constant temperature, equilibrium is approached when backward and forward rates match ie there seems to be no energetic reason to favour one reaction, just a probabilistic reason.

The kinetic equations have solutions for concentrations which evolve in time in such a way that their values converge to a stable state.

The reason is mainly the sort of equations used - first-order differential equations. The reason is neither energetic nor probabilistic.

When system is approaching equilibrium, the rates are not equal during the process. Rates depend on rate constants and concentrations. If the reactants prevail, the forward rate will be higher than the backward rate. Only when the equilibrium is reached, the rates become equal.